# Duplicate Display Name error - Dynamics CRM import

Tags: import, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm importing to CRM using a Data Map from CSV files but I've come up against an error:

> There are two columns in Microsoft Dynamics CRM with the same display
>   name. Change the display name for one of the columns in Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM before importing.

Having fixed a few actual duplicates, the only remaining duplicate I can find is for `timezoneruleversionnumber` and `utcconversiontimezonecode` which both have empty display names and are both system fields (so they're uneditable).

Does anyone have a workaround or a solution for me?

---

Also, probably not relevant, but this import worked last week when it was being done by our CRM expert (uncontactable) so whether he has a work-around or if the fields were added since (possibly automatically) is a mystery.

I've found a few posts on the net where other people are having the same issue ([here](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.crm/attributes-havings-same-display-name-in/189466)) but these all seem to be unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there were duplicates between the 1:N attributes and normal attributes which is now fixed, duplicate (empty) names in system fields will **not** prevent an import.